# Multiple List selection which remembers

Tags: expressionengine

Does anyone know of an add-on which will allow users in the CP to add to a list (similar to P&T List), but the entries for that list are persistent across all entries?

i.e. I have a list with the following sizes:

8
10
12
14

and if the client adds the size '16' - it not only allows them to add it, but all future entries also have that option (and older entries have it too but not selected).

I could have sworn I'd seen something like this in the past, but I can't find it again.

Thanks,

Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carl,

We have an internal field type add-on that I think does what you're asking.

Each instance of a field contains a list that can be initially created along with the field type definition. These options can then be selected from with each channel entry, or new items can be added. These new items will then be in the list for future entries.

A) Does that make any kind of sense (it's a tricky thing to describe)?
B) Do you want me to email you a copy?

Cheers,
Steve.

Comment: Steve - if you could email me a copy that would be awesome and I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

You may have already considered  it but what about Low variables ftw !

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible if the "options" you refer to are entries in an "options" channel and the field in your fieldgroup is a relationship to that channel.  That may be a fair bit heavier than you're looking for though, but it's native.